# Will Microsoft Azure GPU instances provide access to rendered frames?

Tags: azure, nvidia

[Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/building-the-intelligent-cloud-announcing-new-azure-innovations-to-transform-business/) and [NVidia](http://nvidianews.nvidia.com/news/nvidia-gpus-to-accelerate-microsoft-azure) have both released reports of a partnership to bring GPUs to Microsoft Azure. At the moment, I use Amazon Web Services.

I am looking to use [DLL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) to intercept `SwapBuffers()` calls and copy the front/back buffer so that I can stream the frames from the cloud.

However, DLL injection could be superfluous if Microsoft provide some form of API to directly interrogate the GPU and capture the frames.

**Question:**

Does anyone know whether or not Azure will indeed provided some form of functionality to interrogate the GPU and to access the frames rendered?